# Get last committed message in a partition kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using exactly once semantics provided by kafka. Therefore, my producer writes a message within a transaction. While my producer was sending 100th message, right between `send()` and `commitTransaction()`; I killed the producer process.

I read last few uncommitted messages in my topic.

```
Consumer record offset - message number

0                     - 1
2                     - 2
196                   - 99  <- Last committed message by producer
198                   - 100 <- 100th message was sent but not committed
```

Now, when I run consumer with `read_committed` isolation level. It exactly reads from 1-99 messages. But for that I have read entire topic. Eventually, I am going to store millions of messages in a topic. So, reading entire topic is not preferable.

Also, assume that consumer is polling messages from a broker and there is some communication issue with a kafka borker and consumer. Last message read by consumer is let's say offset#50. This means that I could not identify the last committed message in a topic reliably.

I used other methods i.e.

```
seekToEnd() - took me to offset#200
endOffsets() - took me to offset#200
```

*Is there a way to get message that was committed by the Kafka producer **reliably** ?* (In my case, `Offset#196`)

Comment: Can you share the code of your consumer? Also, are you sure that the last committed offset is 198?